# Override a method to attach an event handler to every call

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I am using the `npm` library `request`.

Everytime I call `request()` I would like to actually call `request().on('error', (e) => doSomething())`.

Is there a way to override the `request()` prototype to always call my overridden method?

I have tried setting this before subsequent `request()` calls:

```
request.prototype.on('error', (e) => doSomething())`
```

and I have also tried:

```
request.prototype = (uri) => request(uri).on('error', (e) => doSomething())
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Why not to create your own wrapper and don't try monkeypatch it? Somewhere in your code\module `export function request() { return request.on('error', doSomething) }`

Comment: @EugeneObrezkov that is an obvious and sufficient solution that I did not think about. Thank you for your comment and help. A wrapper is a proper approach here and worked fine.

Comment: FYI, `request()` is now deprecated.  You should probably not be writing new code with it.  A list of alternatives is [here](https://github.com/request/request/issues/3143) which all support promises which is the preferred way of programming and handling asynchronous errors now anyway.  I'm using [`got()`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/got) myself.

Answer (score 0):

Wrapper. I need a wrapper. I was able to solve the general requirement with a simple wrapper method. Thanks to @Eugene Obrekov comment above. I simply did the following:

```
export function request() { return request.on('error', doSomething()) }
```